# Error type DeepTypeOfCollection is not generic

Tags: angular, underscore.js

While running NG BUILD, I am getting an error: type DeepTypeOfCollection is not generic. Also Type alias DeepTypeOfCollection circularly references itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is caused by https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/67318 probably.

Please checkout the GitHub pr and latest comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Resolved by upgrading from @types/underscore ^1.9.2 to 1.11.13